Prove $p,q,r$ are AP if $p\left(\frac{1}{q}+ \frac{1}{r}\right), q\left(\frac{1}{r}+ \frac{1}{p}\right), r\left(\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}\right)$ is AP
How should one approach this question. The following is my attempt:
I started by forming the following equation, which is the inherent property of Arithmetic Progression:
$$2 \cdot q\left(\frac{1}{r}+ \frac{1}{p}\right) = p\left(\frac{1}{q}+ \frac{1}{r}\right) + r\left(\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}\right)$$
By cross multiplication and cancelling common terms, we can show that the above expression can be simplified as $$p^{2}r + p^{2}q + r^{2}q + r^{2}p = 2(q^{2}p + q^{2} r)$$
What should be done after this? I feel getting rid of the square terms will yield the result $2q = p + r$. That would be the end of proof. However, I am not sure how would one get rid of those terms

Try to factor out $(p + r - 2q)$ from the expression.

You're right @Trebor, I missed that. Thank you!

Here is one possible approach (quite similar to your own in some ways):
Expanding $p \left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}\right)$, $q \left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{r}\right)$ and $r \left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}\right)$ gives
$\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{p}{r}\right)$,$\left(\frac{q}{p}+\frac{q}{r}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}\right)$ which are in AP, so we can write
$$\left(\frac{q}{p}+\frac{q}{r}\right)-\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{p}{r}\right)=\left(\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}\right)-\left(\frac{q}{p}+\frac{q}{r}\right).$$
So $2 \left(\frac{q}{p}+\frac{q}{r}\right)-\left(\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}\right)-\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{p}{r}\right)=0$
Multiplying through by $pqr$:
$2(q^2 r+q^2 p)-(r^2 q+r^2 p)-(p^2 r+p^2 q)=0$
$(2q-r-p)(pq+pr+rq)=0$
So either $2q-r-p=0$ in which case $q-p=r-q$ and the proof is finished.
Or $pq+pr+rq=0$ and a bit more work is required.

If we assume p,q,r are positive, then pq,qr,rq are all non negative, they have to be individually 0 in order to be 0, which isn't possible from our assumption. Thus we can cancel that out actually :)

Thank you @Red for providing the proof; and thanks Gwen for the finishing touches!

@EpimuSalon I made a typo, it should have been rp

If $pq+pr+rq=0$ then the given sequence is ${-1,-1,-1}$

Which is an AP. Albeit a trivial one.

For every $r$:$$
(p,q,r)=\left(-\left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)
r,-\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)
r}{\sqrt{3}+1},r\right)
$$
$$
(p,q,r)=\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) r,-\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)
r}{\sqrt{3}-1},r\right)
$$

@RedFive In that case the statement of the problem is false. Take $p=q=1$ and $r=-1/2$

Interesting. If that is the case, can you find the error in my proof? Genuinely interested.

I think the proof is correct, but the thesis only holds when $pq+qr+rp\neq0$

Interesting. Very interesting.

$$p\left(\frac1q+ \frac1r\right), q\left(\frac1r+ \frac1p\right), r\left(\frac1p+ \frac1q\right)\text{ will be in A.P.} $$
$$\iff p\left(\frac{1}{q}+ \frac{1}{r}\right)+1, q\left(\frac{1}{r}+ \frac{1}{p}\right)+1, r\left(\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}\right)+1\text{ are in A.P. }$$
But $p\left(\dfrac{1}{q}+ \dfrac{1}{r}\right)+1=p\left(\underbrace{\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q+\dfrac1r}\right)$ if $p$ is non-zero and finite
Observe the symmetry.
We know $p,q,r$ will be in A.P. $\iff kp,kq,kr, k\ne0$ are in A.P.
So, we need to cancel  out $\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q+\dfrac1r$ which is possible if it is $\ne0$
